# Running two Docker containers (1 reverse proxy nginx, the other a dotnetcore app)

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

First time using docker-compose. Attempting to set up a Nginx container as a webserver and a container that holds my dotnetcore app. The intention is for nginx to pass the call onto Kestrel. Both images build and run but getting error when accessing "http://localhost:8080":

```
proxy_1  | 2019/05/12 16:39:45 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.19.0.2:4000/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

The project structure is as follows:

- Dockersingleproject

  - Dockersingleproject/ (dotnetcore app)

    - *app files'
    - DockerFile
  - Nginx/

    - nginx.conf
    - DockerFile
  - docker-compose.yml

I am under the impression that the issue is regarding the connection between the web server container and the app container is refusing but I cannot figure out why. Below is the app Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build

WORKDIR /Dockersingleproject
COPY bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:4000
EXPOSE 4000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Dockersingleproject.dll"]
```

The app docker file is exposing port 4000. The nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream docker-nginx {
        server app:4000;
    } 

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-nginx;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_buffers         8 16k;  # Buffer pool = 8 buffers of 16k
            proxy_buffer_size     16k;    # 16k of buffers from pool used for headers
        }
    } 
}
```

The server is listening on port 8080 and proxies the request to port 4000 on server "app". Which is defined in the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context:  ./Dockersingleproject
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"

  proxy:
    build:
      context:  ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - app
```

The app service maps port 4000 requests to 4000 and in my head this should be working.

The IP of the nginx container is: 172.19.0.3
The IP of the app container is: 172.19.0.2

Please let me know where my confusion lies. I am on the point of accusing my PC of being the issue. Any information is appreciated.

Getting Connection refused when accessing the site resulting in a nginx 502 bad gateway

Comment: hey im trying to reproduce your issue but getting error 503 when trying to pull the dotnet image. am i missing something?

Comment: @EfratLevitan Hi, the dotnet base image statement was generated by Visual Studio when adding Docker support. Not sure why you are getting a 503 sorry.

Comment: You're exposing `app` on the host's `:4000` (which you probably shouldn't do) but, because you are, you can confirm that the .NET container is working correctly by curl'ing the endpoint (`curl --request GET http://localhost:4000`) from the host. If that works, then the issue is in your Nginx config.

Comment: Because you intend Nginx to proxy your .NET container, you needn't expose .NET to the host. One way to avoid this is to just use `ports: - ":4000" but it's better to use `expose' as this doesn't expose any host point. In other feedback, `docker-compose` is now at `version: 3` and using `3` you don't need to `links: - app` as this is implicit from the service names.

Comment: Your Dockerfile container redundant commands: `FROM ... as base` is not used. and `FROM ... as build` doesn't use the `build` reference so the `as build` can be dropped. See [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for where you'd use this.

Answer (score 1):

This uses the Microsoft-provided ASP.NET Core sample:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:

  app:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
    expose:
    - "80"

  proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

**NB**

- The ASP.NET Core sample runs on `:80` and is `expose`'d
- The Nginx container also runs on `:80` and is exposed on the host on `:8080`

nginx.conf:

```
events {}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:80;
    }
  }
}
```

**NB**

- Nginx listens on `:80` because its container requires it
- The proxy configuration references the service name (`app`) on `:80`

And:

```sh
curl \
--silent \
--write-out "%{http_code}" \
--output /dev/null \
http://localhost:8080

200
```